# footer does not inherit the positioning property?

Tags: html, css

i was going smooth with my html and css codes until this problem i am facing now and i don't know what is happening.

my html patterns is like this.

in the top is   `<div id="header">` which does not have any fixed width. i have used an image and used the repeat-x property. and in the header i have navigation menu wrapped in the container of 940px;

in middle is the `<div id="content">` which is wrapped with container of the same 940px;

till the content div my codes are fine. now i am facing the problem in positioning the footer correctly. my footer should not have any fixed width and should not be wrapped in the container. so i defined the footer div outside of the content and container div that is right before the closing of body and html tag.

when i do this the footer image which have the dimension of 50px X 290px;  goes upward and is placed from the content div. it does not come to the bottom. i am using temporarily `margin-top:1600px;` to position it correctly which is wrong.

why is it not inheriting the position, i tried giving every position attribute. it is not working :(,

what am i missing?

P.S: the code was lil lengthy so i didnt post it here, instead i explained what is happening. if you still want to see my code i can try and put the minimal code.

thank you

EDIT : Here is the link to jsfiddle and my code.  http://jsfiddle.net/32ShZ/

Comment: It would certainly help us to help you if you could post the minimum code required to demonstrate the problem. Or you can link to a live demo (jsbin, or jsfiddle are both great for this, which is even better than posting code here, since we can see it all live, and in action).

Comment: done, please look my post i have posted the link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been that the `#footer` wasn't clearing the floated divs (and gosh, you *do* like your divs don't you? 70? In *one* document?). So, adding:

```
#footer {
clear: both;
width:940px; /* copied from your other divs */
}
```

seems to have worked. I'm not sure, as yet, why the `#footer` isn't respecting `margin: 0 auto;` but still, it seems to be moving on the right tracks. Have a look at: [jsfiddle.net/32ShZ/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/32ShZ/3/) (you'll note I've used some jQuery to populate all the divs, so I could see what was where. And added a `background-color` to `#footer` to make it more visible, these are, clearly, optional).

---

**Edited** in response to comment:

> i am confused about the jQuery code. what is it exactly.?

[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) is a JavaScript library, written to provide a cross-browser compatible abstraction, so that, for the most part, one set of code should produce consistent results cross-browser, from IE to Chrome. Its api is available to review online, over at: [jQuery.com](http://api.jquery.com/).

```
$('div').each(
    function(i) {
        $(this).append('<p>Div (' + i + ') ' + $(this).attr('id') +'</p>');
    }
);
```

The code I used, step by step:

1. found all the `div` elements on the page, `$('div')`
2. iterated over each of those elements, and applied a function. The `i` is an iterator `.each(function(i){...})`
3. worked on the current element, `$(this)`
4. appended a `<p>` to the element, with text contents `.append('

   Div (' + i + ') ' + $(this).attr('id') +'

   ')
5. the `$(this).attr('id')` section looks at the current element and finds its 'id' attribute, inserting that into the string.

Comment: heehe, thank you. you see this is the first time i am coding properly. :D, i am desperate to improve my code. do you have any tip on improving my codes. ill just check the code and get back to you .

Comment: clear:both works perfectly fine :), thanks a lot. i am confused about the jQuery code. what is it exactly.?

Comment: @Ibrahim, I've edited a very brief synopsis of what jQuery is, and how the code I used works/what it does.

Comment: thank you i got it. looks like i have another problem now. i am unable to add the padding-top or margin-top on the footer div, the footer image is fixed right after the container and does not move i want a space gap of 20px between the last div and the footer :(

Comment: corrected my code and solved all the problem. thanks a lot for your effort.